# Unable to waterlog doors 1.13 Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This one makes me feel really stupid, but here it goes.

Can you waterlog doors in Minecraft 1.13?
I've tried right clicking the door with a water bucket, top and bottom, shift-right clicking the door with a water bucket, top and bottom, and crying on the door top and bottom. I can't find anything online, but I thought I had read about this before.

Is there some kind of command? Is there a piston trick? I would like to be able to do this, but I can't think of anything else to try.

[image]

PICTURE OF WATERLOGGED FENCE AND COBBLE WALL.

**EDIT**
I tried placing the door in water (fully surrounded except for base block which is necessary for door placement:

[image]

No such luck.

I tried placing a waterlogged block above it:

[image]

Yet again, no luck. ):

Comment: What do you mean by waterlog a door..? Do you mean to place water source blocks where a door is placed? I dont know if this has ever been possible. IIRC (which Im probably wrong here), but I thought water always would cause a door to be removed and then would float away. Can you elaborate for me?

Comment: In 1.13 update Aquatic, you can waterlog blocks that do not occupy the whole space. I edited it to have a picture of this.

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean now. I do not know the answer unforunately. What would happen if you placed the door in the lake in the image? Or rather than trying to right click on the door with water, what would happen if you placed a block above it and had the water flow onto the door?

Comment: @Mr________ Have you tried using a debug stick? /give @p debug_stick, then left click the door until you see "waterlogged = false", then right click. Does that work?

Comment: done @Kyle Rone

Comment: @SpiceWeasel, I will try that but I want to be able to do this In survival. - Just tried it and the door just kept flipping textures and rotations. No water /:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is officially considered a bug: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-125351

Doors are an especially bad case of this, since they generate with shipwrecks. 1.13 has a lot of pretty bad bugs, which is one of the reasons why I recommend staying on 1.12.2 at least until 1.14.0 is out.

Comment: Thank you! This good to know. I couldn't tell if it was a bug or just a weird Mojang/ Microsoft decision.

Comment: It was definitely a weird decision to only select certain blocks to be waterloggable, since it was apparently meant to be all non-full blocks. And since 1.13 also introduced complex hitboxes for blocks, that would have been the perfect opportunity to make blocks waterloggable by clicking on an inner face, no special handling for single blocks needed. That they didn't do that also causes [MC-134891](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-134891).